# Accessing all email on Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-server

I would like to programmatically be able to access all the emails stored in an exchange server in order to do some text analysis on those emails. How would I go about this, assuming I had all the necessary permissions and direct access to the server?

Answer (score 0):

My gut says you should use eDiscovery tools built into Exchange, but I'm not entirely sure that will accomplish what you want.  eDiscovery does what it was designed to do pretty well, but that's entirely focused around finding emails in a date range or via keyword.